# Como faço para colocar um registro em uma nova página utilizando JasperReports se este transbordar a última página?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasper, jaspersoft-studio

Estou usando [jaspersoft-studio](/questions/tagged/jaspersoft-studio) `6.2.0` e [jasper-reports](/questions/tagged/jasper-reports) lib também `6.2.0`.

Eu tenho um relatório e na seção de detalhes alguns dos registros na tabela podem passar de uma página para outra e o seu conteúdo é escrito em uma nova página dividindo-o. É possível para a engine perceber que o conteúdo transborda a página e imprimir todo o registro como sendo o primeiro na próxima página?

Aqui está como o relatório está sendo gerado no momento:
[image: Aqui está como o relatório está sendo gerado no momento]

O que eu preciso é que o último registro passe a ser impresso na página seguinte ao invés da página anterior. É possível alcançar este resultado utilizando jasperreports?

Answer (score 1):

Selecione a band que esta os campos que você não pretende quebrar linha, e vá na aba de `Properties` você vai em `Advanced` e marque com true a opção `Print In First Whole Band` a mesma diz que a sua band deve ser impressa inteiramente em uma única linha.